# Cursor value into BasicNameValuePairs

Tags: android

I am trying to send a value to a php server.  I want the cursor value to be place below, next to "server".

```
SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT server FROM server_detail ;", null);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("server", cursor));
```

Can someone please show me the correct way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Get server in cursor to a temporary string and pass to nameValuePairs. Something like below.

```
String serverName = cur.getString(0);

nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("server", serverName ));
```

Note: I haven't validated the syntax

Comment: make sense, thanks! But the getString does not want to accept "server" as a value.  Ill keep looking.

Comment: server field is at index 0 in your query, so cur.getString(0); should work.

Comment: .. you may want to consider doing a Cursor#moveToNext() and validate the return value (it should be `true`).